# How to run Pyscript in React?

Tags: python, reactjs, pyscript

I'm trying to use [PyScript](https://pyscript.net/) in NextJS, but I'm seeing several errors. I have no clue how to make a React component of PyScript. Has anyone successfully used PyScript in ReactJS? Thanks,

```
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
        <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
      </Head>
      <div className="mx-auto container">
        <py-repl></py-repl>
        <py-script>
          import datetime as dt
          pyscript.write(‘today’, dt.date.today().strftime(‘%A %B %d, %Y’))
          def compute_pi(n):
              pi = 2
              for i in range(1,n):
                  pi *= 4 * i ** 2 / (4 * i ** 2 - 1)
              return pi
          pi = compute_pi(100000)
          pyscript.write(‘pi’, f’π is approximately {pi:.3f}’)
        </py-script>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Error 1.

```
Type error: Property 'py-repl' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.
```

Error 2.

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
```

Error 3.
The above `<py-script>` causes

```
JsException(PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 429, in eval_code .run(globals, locals) File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 300, in run coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals) File "", line 2, in File "", line 129, in write AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'innerHTML' )
```

Comment: One way to make your life easier for you is to skip py-script altogether and use the underlying Pyodide framework directly - which is used py-script internally.  This way you have better control over loading, entry points, such https://pyodide.org/en/stable/

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it out.

Comment: You can still directly interface with Pyodide in a PyScript application. There is one exception. PyScript includes its own CSS styles which modify a lot of DOM elements visually. Just exclude the pyscript.css file.

Comment: @JohnHanley didn't know that it is possible to access Pyodide API from PyScript. Is there any page about it? I still couldn't find comprehensive documents. Yes, as you said, PyScript comes with CSS and I sometimes feel like customizing a cell.

Comment: Pyodide has good documentation on available APIs.

Answer (score 0):

you can set python script into `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

```js
<div
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `<py-script>
    from datetime import datetime
    now = datetime.now()
    now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
    </py-script>`,
  }}
/>
```

---

Or

`PyScript-React` is not yet available, but you can follow it -
https://github.com/Py4Js/PyScript-React

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';

const Sample = ()  => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
                <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
            </Head>
            <py-config></py-config>
            <py-script>
                print('Hello, World!')
            </py-script>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Sample;
```